# php echo an alert box and header redirect in a same file

Tags: javascript, php

I try to run the following tasks

```
<?php
     echo "<script>alert('yes');</script>";
     flush();
     header('Location: ' . 'index.php');
     exit;
?>
```

but just one task could work. if I remove flush(), I will not see the alert box. If I use flush() the header can not redirect.

any suggestions or solutions

Comment: You cannot send header to another location after echo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: `header` sends a server-side redirect, alert is JavaScript which is ran client-side. You can't run client-side code before server-side code. You should use JavaScript for the redirect instead.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out something work in my purpose, but not the thing I want.

```
<?php
     echo "<script>alert('yes');</script>";
     ob_flush();
     usleep(1);
   # ob_end_flush();
     echo "abcd";
     echo "abcd";
     echo "abcd";
     echo "abcd";

     usleep(3);
     #ob_start();
     echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=' . 'http://mintnet.net/' . '" />'; 
    # exit(header("Location: home.php"));
?>
```